# Generate one output-file with webpack and typescript

Tags: webpack

I'm just getting started with webpack and need to transpile and bundle a TypeScript application. In this app, I have several imports to other classes, that I want to be included in one single output js-file.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
devtool: 'source-map',
devServer: {
    inline: true,
},
entry: {
    vendor: ["./main"]
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['babel?{"presets":["es2015"],"cacheDirectory":true}', "awesome-typescript-loader"],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    }]
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'mylib.module.js',
    library: 'mylib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
}
}
```

Unfortunatly this config just generated me the transpiled source for the `main.ts` without all the other classes. Can someone point me to the correct configuration for this task?

I already tried to find the solution in the webpack-docs, but I can't find  somethin in there ...

Kind regards

Comment: Webpack includes everything that is being imported, starting from the entry point. Did you mean that you want to expose them as well such that you can use them as `mylib.importedClass`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly thats not the case. In my main.ts i have a `import {myclass} from './myclass.file'` and the content of the myclass.file is not added to the resulting js-file. I'm using webpack 1.15, if that helps ...

Comment: Let me ask again. Do you try to use it as `mylib.myclass`? Not exposing it doesn't mean that it isn't included.

Comment: The libray name is mylib, and I dont try to expose them as mylib.myclass. I'm just exposing my main-class on mylib, not the classes that my main-class imports

Comment: Here is some code to visualize how I'm trying to use it: https://pastebin.com/fkSmGsi4